# Unity DI: Resolving from per-request to global singleton to per-request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a controller calling a global singleton calling a per-request-instance in the context of a ASP.NET WebAPI. Basically

per-request => singleton => per-request

Is the below setup correct? I'm particularly worried about the second per-request instance, since it could be user-based claims.

Or is that an anti-pattern and the singleton should receive (per-request) dependencies from the controller?

```
    // UnityConfig.cs, the Resolver uses CreateChildContainer()
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer unity)
    {
        // global singleton
        unity.RegisterType<MessageContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        // instance per request
        unity.RegisterType<ClaimsContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    }

    // API controller
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly MessageContext _message;

        public FormController(MessageContext message)
        {
            _message = message;
        }

        public Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction()
        {
            _message.FireAndForget();
            return Ok();
        }
    }

    // global singleton to keep connection pool
    public class MessageContext
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _unity;

        public MessageContext(IUnityContainer unity)
        {
            _unity = unity;
        }

        public Task FireAndForget()
        {
            // resolve per request
            var claim = _unity.Resolve<ClaimsContext>().MyClaim);
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: See: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/

Comment: The question, if a call to `_unity.Resolve` would resolve correctly, still remains, but I guess it's smelly code. Refactoring probably best!

Comment: As the blog post explains, a consumer will keep its dependency alive for the lifetime of the consumer. This means that if you inject a per-request in a singleton, the per-request dependency will survive the request, which almost always leads to unintended consequences (either now or in the future). Prevent having this and find a way to detect these kinds of errors using a unit test (or switch to a container that detects these kinds of problems for you out of the box).

Comment: Understood that and it's also clear that above code is not well designed, but `ClaimsContext` is resolved manually vs. constructor injection and not held in a private property in `MessageContext`. The reference only lives for the duration of the `FireAndForget` call. So what you are saying still applies in that situation? This case is not mentioned in the blog post afaik.

Comment: You are applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) in your MessageContext, which is bad as well. You should prevent both Service Locator ánd Captive Dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, above sample code needs to be restructured. To fix, I split `MessageContext` into a long-lived and a short-lived part. The short-lived part receives the short-lived `ClaimsContext`, while the long-lived part only holds onto long-lived connections.